# Get first level items size in Windows cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, installation

I want to list only  the first level folders sizes of a giving folder.
Dir /s will also display is going deep and displays dir command of all sub folders and files as well.
But I need something like

```
Dir FolderName
```

Resulting:

SubFlder1 1G,
SubFolder2 2G
etc.

Some details:

- I am in the middle of reinstalling windows that went wrong, and the "old" system partition (c:) was deleted
- I want to explore the "old" D: partition to backup data before continue
- Thus I can only use the Win10 installation command line utility (opened with shift+F10 in the activation code screen that is displayed at the beginning of the installation process), or of course any another utility available during installation.

Is it possible somehow?

tx

Comment: Something like `For /d %A in (FolderName\*) do @Dir %A /A-D|findstr ":\\ File("`?

Comment: @LotPings Not sure I fully understand...what are you trying to filter with the  **findstr**? what is the idea?

Comment: The for iterates the subfolders, each dir lists the files including the footer with number of files and  bytes consumed by these files. Findstr simply removes all other lines. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

To demonstrate my one liner, current directory is Q:\Test

```
Q:\Test> tree 2017
Q:\TEST\2017
├───01
├───02
├───03
└───04

Q:\Test> For /d %A in (2017\*) do @Dir %A /A-D 2>Nul|find /V "/"|find /v "Dir("|find /V "Vol"

 Directory of Q:\Test\2017\01


 Directory of Q:\Test\2017\02

               2 File(s)        414.805 bytes

 Directory of Q:\Test\2017\04


 Directory of Q:\Test\2017\03

               1 File(s)            171 bytes
```

Comment: Tried that...Looks like findstr is not available in the installation command line

Comment: Replaced findstr with find and different strategy, see changed batch.

Comment: Please see the next post

Answer (score 0):

two issues with that

1. The Dir parameter `%A` should be encapsulated in double quotes in case folder name contains space. Took me a while to understand that.
2. It works only in case the folder tree has only one sub level. But when the sub folder contains folder(s) as well the folder size for that folder returns only the files within that specific folder, ignoring the sub folders items...Not sure the `Dir` approach fits here.